# Magento 2 - Column tier_price is set NULL in catalog_product_index_price table

Tags: magento2, php, price, catalog, reindex

I tried to populate column tier_price of catalog_product_index_price table but every time that reindex this column return NULL.

[image]

Why tier_price column return NULL every time i reindex magento 2?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those index tables are populated from values in other tables, if you try to edit this tables manually or with another process your directly added values will be removed

Tier Price comes from information related to the product through the backend: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html

Probably the table you'd be targeting is **catalog_product_entity_tier_price**